# Regex pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

`$string= 'This is example string \add[name1]{added} and \remove[name2]{removed text}  \change[name1]{this}{to}.'`

Here  `\add[name1]{added}` should be replaced to `added` (\add = string is added)

`\remove[name2]{removed text}` should be replaced to empty text ( `removed text` is removed)

`\change[name1]{this}{to}` should be replaced to `this` (here \change means `to` is changed to `this`)

**Expected output**`This is example string added and this.`

I tried regex for this,

```
preg_match('/\\add\[name1]{(.*?)}/',$string,$match) //for add (\add)
str_replace($match[0],$match[1],$match[0])
//problem is [name] is not constant so how to get the string between
//"\add[anything]{" and "}" I will apply same regex for this
//"\remove[anything]{" and "}" too.
```

For `\change[anything]{string1}{string2}`should be replaced to `string1`

Comment: in this `\add[name1]{added}`, did you want to replace the match with the characters inside curly braces or you want to replace the match with the string `added`?

Comment: That should be replaced with the string which is in between curly braces

Comment: Perhaps you could try [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for a more precise replace.

Comment: @Vidhya did you try to print the $string variable? php would consider `\r` as carriage return. correct your input string.

Comment: I changed `$string `with single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with back references, e.g. `$1`. Just remember to escape your backslashes twice, once for PHP and once for the RegEx:

```
<?php
$string= 'This is example string '
    . '\add[name1]{added} '
    . 'and '
    . '\remove[name2]{removed text}'
    . '\change[name1]{this}{to}.';

//$string = preg_replace('#\\add\[.*?\]\{(.*?)\}#', '$1', $string);

// Apply add
$string = preg_replace('/\\\\add\\[.*?\\]\\{(.*?)\\}/', '$1', $string);

// Apply change
$string = preg_replace('/\\\\change\\[.*?\\]\\{(.*?)\\}\\{.*?\\}/', '$1', $string);

// Apply remove
$string = preg_replace('/\\\\remove\\[.*?\\]\\{(.*?)\\}/', '', $string);

echo $string, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
This is example string added and this.
```

Comment: one more query, `\add[name]{\textbf{text}and}` if its like this the output should be `\textbf{text}and`. So how to change pattern for this. I meant between the curly braces if another curly braces exists what would be the pattern

Comment: Put this before the regular `\add` replacement: `$string = preg_replace('/\\\\add\\[\w+\\]\\{(\\\\\textbf\\{\w+\\}.*?\\})/', '$1', $string);`. You can do like that when you know the exact format of the inner string, but if it would be nested more levels you will need a more complicated solution.

Comment: Actually `textbf`is not standard format it may vary. I need the string between the curly braces and if the string has curly braces with it that also should be extracted. For example: `{stringwith{}}` output `string{}`